# Why are women not allowed to go out alone even in today's society?

Tags: women, mahram, protection

Men are allowed to go out to anywhere they like and at anytime they wish. Women on the other hand are restricted and can only go out with a mahram by their side. I understand that this is because men are obliged to protect women. However in today's society women can go out without needing protection, especially at times of day light. Also what if the men are at work and the female needs to go out for something?

Comment: This article may help you: http://www.questionsonislam.com/question/it-permissible-muslim-woman-go-out-or-travel-alone

Comment: What's the basis for the statement in the title?

Comment: @ozbek Women were told not to go out alone before because men might harm them and it wasn't practiced in society either. However today women go out alone all the time without being troubled by men.

Answer (score 5):

**Sunni view:** The most accepted Sunni view is that it is permissible for a women to travel alone for up to three days.

> Abd Allah ibn Umar (Allah be pleased with him) narrates that the
>   Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give him peace) said: **“A woman
>   must not travel for three days except with a Mahram”**. [Sahih 
>   Bukhari, no. 1036 & Sahih Muslim].

However, some modern scholars argue that if it's safe for the women to travel, then it is permissible for them to travel alone without any restrictions. They generally cite the following narrations as evidence.

> (Another chain) from 'Adi bin Hatim who said: "I went to the Prophet
>   (ﷺ) while he was sitting in the Masjid, the people said: 'This is 'Adi
>   bin Hatim.' And I came without having a treaty nor a writ. When I was
>   brought to him, he took my hand. Prior to that he had said: 'I hope
>   that Allah will place his hand in my hand.'" He said: "He stood with
>   me, and a woman and a boy met him and said: 'We have a need from you.'
>   He stood with them, until he was finished dealing with what they
>   wanted. Then he took me by the hand until he brought me to his house.
>   A slave girl brought him a cushion to sit on, and I sat in front of
>   him. He expressed thanks and praise for Allah then said: 'What has
>   caused you to flee from saying La Ilaha Illallah? Do you know of
>   another god other than Him?'" He said: "I said: 'No.'" He said: "Then
>   he talked for some time, and then said: 'You refuse to say Allahu
>   Akbar because you know that there is something greater than Allah?'"
>   He said: "I said: 'No.' He said: 'Indeed the Jews are those who Allah
>   is wrath with, and the Christians have strayed.'" He said: "I said:
>   'Indeed I am a Muslim, Hanif.'" He said: "I saw his face smiling with
>   happiness." He said: "Then he ordered that I stop with him at the home
>   of a man from the Ansar, whom he would frequently visit in the
>   mornings and the evenings. When I was with him at night, a people in
>   woolen garments of these Nimar (a cloth with certain patters, and the
>   word appeared before) came. Then he performed Salat and stood to
>   encourage them (the people) to give (charity) to them. Then he said:
>   'Even with a Sa' or half a Sa', or a handful or part of a handful, to
>   save the face of one of you from the heat of Hell, or the Fire. And
>   even if it be by a date or a part of a date - for indeed one of you
>   shall meet Allah and it shall be said to him what I say to you: "Have
>   I not given hearing and seeing to you?" He shall say: "Of course." It
>   will be said: "Have I not given you wealth and children?" He shall
>   say: "Of course." It will be said: "So where is what you have sent
>   forth for yourself?" He will look before him and behind him, on his
>   right and on his left, but he shall not find anything to protect his
>   face from the heat of Hell. Let one of you protect his face from the
>   Fire, even if with part of a date, and if he does not find that, then
>   with a good statement. For indeed I do not fear poverty for you -
>   **Allah will aid you and grant you, such that a woman can travel on her
>   camel howda from Yathrib to Al-Hirah, or further, without fear of
>   being robbed.'** I began thinking to myself: "Where would the thieves of
>   Taiy' be then?"'
>
> [Sahih Bukhari Vol. 5, Book 44, Hadith -2951]
>
> Once, during the days of trouble and torture in Makka, I went to God’s
>   Messenger, who was sitting in the shade of the Ka‘ba. I was still a
>   slave in the hands of the Makkans then. They inflicted on me severe
>   tortures. Unable to endure those tortures any more, I requested God’s
>   Messenger to pray to God for help and salvation. But he turned towards
>   me and said:
>
> By God, previous communities had to endure more pitiless tortures.
>   Some of them were made to lie in ditches and cut in two with saws but
>   this did not make them forsake their faith. They were skinned alive
>   but they never became weak against the enemy. Surely God will perfect
>   this religion, but you display undue haste. **A day will come when a
>   woman will travel alone by herself from San’a to Hadramawt fearing
>   nothing but wild beasts.** However, you show impatience.
>
> [Bukhari & Abu Dawad](http://www.answering-christianity.com/prophecies_by_prophet_muhammad.htm)

Traditional scholars reject this view stating that futuristic events don't count as evidence for permissibility.

**Shia view:** According to mainstream Shia scholars, it is permissible for a woman to travel alone.

Comment: With the second hadith I agree with the scholars. The hadith only says that a time will come when women will travel alone but not necessarily that it should or would be permissible.

Answer (score 1):

Alsalmo ALikom.

it is not "going out", but it is "traveling". Women are not allowed to travel alone for long distances without mahram, and this is for her protection as you mentioned. If the travel is safe, i mean surely safe and secure, in the road, transport means , and the destination, then she may travel **without** mahram.

Wa Allah Aalam.

This is a refrence from Egypt's Dar-Alifta

http://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=3019&text=travel

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the idea of Mahram about protecting women and ONLY for protecting women to be EXTREMELY lacking. Women need Mahram to ALSO protect men who sees women. When a woman is walking alone without anyone or anything protecting her(and living alone), it can make a man desire for her. The longer she is alone, the more.

The concept of Mahram, I believe, is to also protect men from having such feelings. God DID NOT give men desire for women from sight and love women without even talking to them in order for them to be TRIED even under the rules of Islam.

The rules of Islam is to make the LEAST amount of fitnah for all things for anyone and to live the best kind of life. Islam teaches us to let go of many worldly desires for Allah and live through many hard times, and even have things or whom you love to go away.

In order for MEN and WOMEN to coexist in peace, we need to follow the guidelines of Allah. Rules for women in Islam is mostly about not going out alone, but they are not given the responsibility to pray in the Masjid, work to provide food and wealth to family, and many other things.

Allah has COMMANDED Men to go pray in the Masjid and COMMANDED to take care of family, so women should consider what guys are going through and what they feel if they also plan to go outside(try to wear hijab nicely, avoid mingling or interacting with guys unless neccessary, etc).

Allah knows best, I am speaking this from my own logic and understand. I can very well be wrong. Do not take my word for it. I am willing to read the comments made to this post, inshallah!

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. This answer lacks any evidences to support your claims and looks more like your own interpretation of the matter which is forgetting that men are asked to lower their gaze too and hold on not to look at women they don't know.

Comment: "forgetting that men are asked to lower their gaze too and hold on not to look at women they don't know," you seem to also be forgetting that woman has to also do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all. I would like to say Islam does not allow woman to travel alone by herself, but this does not mean that woman is not good or faithful, no no, because she is physically is not strong enough to protect herself, so Islam prefers for her to go out or travel along with her mahram so as to grantee her safety of being attacked by any one.

Answer (score -1):

I’m female in the UK and went for a walk in a nearby national park with a female friend during the daytime.

There is no Fitnah (temptations) and no Khalwah (being alone with opposite gender). And it’s VERY unlikely to be attacked. It was a popular walking route with many older women walking alone, or walking their dog.

It was good for mental health to be in nature and spend time with my female friend.

I traveled alone for many years before marrying my husband, and never once been robbed, attacked etc. I know a male who was robbed at night, so both genders are advised not to walk alone at night by western standards. And told especially to be careful in crime ridden areas. We are told of you are in a group of more than one person you are safer. People will rob anyone if they are alone.

Of course there is risk of danger with anything, and to have a protector with you is positive. However in the western world you call the police and don’t get into fights yourself where possible. We are not allowed guns here. How it works is if someone assaults you, the police punish and send to prison.

In the past this rule makes perfect sense. But we have laws now that make it safer than it’s ever been.

As long as you are in safe area, no Fitnah, no Khalwah etc. I know many will disagree, but I hope they become aware this is very different environment to other countries, and it really does make a huge difference.