# Which mainstream Shia scholars say it's permissible for a woman to travel alone?

Tags: women, shiism, travelling

From Mohammad Sakib Arifin's answer to [Why are women not allowed to go out alone even in today's society?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31010/17163):

> **Shia view**: According to mainstream Shia scholars, it is permissible for a woman to travel alone.

Based on the author's track record on this site, I suspect it's a correct claim, but...

**Question**: Which mainstream Shia scholars say it's permissible for a woman to travel alone?

Googling revealed inconsistent posts on ShiaChat, and I'm not sure how much I can trust them.  Googling [`site:sistani.org woman travel`](https://www.google.com/#q=site:sistani.org+woman+travel) and [`site:leader.ir woman travel`](https://www.google.com/#q=site:leader.ir+woman+travel) didn't reveal any easy, general answers.

Comment: http://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=3019&text=travel maybe this is related (sunni)